# How to use exiftool in python subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, exiftool

I want to read a file containing folder list, then search images in each and apply an exiftool command to retrieve metadatas formatted in a csv file.

```
    f = open("exifs.csv","w")
    f.write("id;name;E;N;Alt_gps;date;iso;speed;oberture\n")

    for line in file:
        print (line)
        if not line.startswith('#') :
            line2 = line.strip()
            for photo in os.listdir(line2):

                subprocess.call(shlex.split('exiftool -p $directory;$filename;$GPSLongitude#;$GPSLatitude#;$GPSAltitude#;$DateTimeOriginal;$iso;$ExposureTime;$Fnumber -f -c "%f" {x}'.format(x=photo)), stdout=f)

    f.close()
```

Actually that just list all images contained in folders without applying subprocess call to exiftool.

Comment: I'd suggest rather than looping and calling exiftool for each file, instead just let exiftool read the file list directly with the [`-@` (Argfile) option](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#ARGFILE).  Use `-@ Filelist.txt` and exiftool will process all the files in the list.  You'll find this much faster than calling exiftool for each file individually (see [Common Mistake #3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M3))

Comment: Ok, so I've got to produce the list file before passing it to exiftool. But what about the fact that my subprocess.call doesn't apply to each file found in my loop?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with that, as I have no experience with python, just exiftool.

Comment: Nevertheless I thank you for the advice, since I found another way to make it with the -@ option , not python but exiftool.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this in Python (3.11) while passing one command to ExifTool ( +more current methods and libraries).

I'm assuming your text file looks something like the following `paths.txt`:

```
# Paths:
  C:\Path\To\dir1 
  C:\Path\To\dir2 
  C:\Path\To\dir3
```

In the following I collect the file paths from the text file and list out all of the paths at the end of the command when it is passed to ExifTool through `subprocess.run()`.

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess, shlex
# Get lines from text file
with open('paths.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
# Get a list of file paths from the dir paths
fp_list = [fp for l in lines if not l.startswith('#') for fp in Path(l.strip()).iterdir()]
# The pathlib equivalent to os.listdir() is iterdir()
args = shlex.split('exiftool -p $directory;$filename;$GPSLongitude#;$GPSLatitude#;$GPSAltitude#;$DateTimeOriginal;$iso;$ExposureTime;$Fnumber -f -c "%f"')
# Pass all of the file paths in one ExifTool command
proc = subprocess.run([args, *fp_list], capture_output=True)
# run() replaced call(), run() returns the CompletedProcess class
# Write the headers and ExifTool output to a csv
with open("output.csv", "wb") as output:
    output.write("id;name;E;N;Alt_gps;date;iso;speed;oberture\n".encode())
    # Setting capture_output=True captures output in stdout and stderr
    output.write(proc.stdout)
```

`output.csv`:

```
id;name;E;N;Alt_gps;date;iso;speed;oberture
C:/Path/To/dir1;test1.jpg;-;-;-;2023:03:15 00:00:00;100;1/10;1
C:/Path/To/dir2;test2.jpg;-;-;-;2023:03:15 00:00:00;100;1/10;1
C:/Path/To/dir3;test3.jpg;-;-;-;2023:03:15 00:00:00;100;1/10;1
```